# How to allocate a fixed area for a span text

Tags: html, css

I want to make my span elements text in a fixed position something like this

```
Mon  9-10pm  2300000  23%
T    9-10pm  23       23%
```

but while trying using below html I am getting this

```
Mon 9-10pm 2300000 23%
T 9-10pm 23 23%
```

I tried to align each span using below css,but when any of the word is small or big it changes the positon of other text.

```
position: relative;
left:15px;
top: 5px;
```

HTML

```html
<div class="dataContainer">
  <span class="weekdays">
                      Mon
                      </span>
  <span class="time">
                      9-10pm
                      </span>
  <span class="subscriberCounts">
                      2300000
                      </span>
  <span class="border">
                      </span>
  <span class="subscriberPercentage">
                      23%
                      </span>
</div>
<div class="dataContainer">
  <span class="weekdays">
                      T
                      </span>
  <span class="time">
                      9-10pm
                      </span>
  <span class="subscriberCounts">
                      23
                      </span>
  <span class="border">
                      </span>
  <span class="subscriberPercentage">
                      23%
                      </span>
</div>
```

What css can I add to allocate some fixed area for each span element text?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/jzp83rwf/1/)

Comment: Use Flexbox, just google it.
Here a badly optimized and not mobile friendly but simple version: https://jsfiddle.net/q3ecbgjk/

Comment: `Display: block` is what you need - see answer below.

Comment: Use a table - it is tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a table - this is tabular data and a table would do exactly what you are after with the added bonus of equal column widths without you having to specify a specific width:

```css
th {
  text-align: left;
}

th, td { padding:5px; }
```

```html
<table class="dataContainer">
  <tr>
    <th class="weekdays" scope="row">
      Mon
    </th>
    <td class="time">
      9-10pm
    </td>
    <td class="subscriberCounts">
      2300000
    </td>
    <td class="border">
    </td>
    <td class="subscriberPercentage">
      23%
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="weekdays" scope="row">
      T
    </th>
    <td class="time">
      9-10pm
    </td>
    <td class="subscriberCounts">
      23
    </td>
    <td class="border">
    </td>
    <td class="subscriberPercentage">
      23%
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you really want to use a span, then I would make it inline block and give it a width so you don';t need to float things:

```css
.dataContainer > span {
    display:inline-block;
}

.weekdays {
   font-weight:bold;
   width:3.5em;
}

.time {
   width:4em;
}

.subscriberCounts {
   width:4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataContainer">
  <span class="weekdays">
                  Mon
                  </span>
  <span class="time">
                  9-10pm
                  </span>
  <span class="subscriberCounts">
                  2300000
                  </span>
  <span class="border">
                  </span>
  <span class="subscriberPercentage">
                  23%
                  </span>
</div>
<div class="dataContainer">
  <span class="weekdays">
                  T
                  </span>
  <span class="time">
                  9-10pm
                  </span>
  <span class="subscriberCounts">
                  23
                  </span>
  <span class="border">
                  </span>
  <span class="subscriberPercentage">
                  23%
                  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: can I use div instead of span since by default div is block element?

Comment: You can use what you like, as you have control over what display it is - a span starts off as inline

Answer (score 1):

Like this.  Not sure what border does as its empty.  I've left red borders on the classes for the moment so you can see the spans - just remove them when you have the sizing as you need.

```css
.dataContainer
{
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.weekdays, .time, .subscriberCounts, .border, .subscriberPercentage
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.weekdays
{
  width: 50px;
}

.time
{
  width: 80px;
}

.subscriberCounts
{
  width: 100px;
}

.subscriberPercentage
{
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataContainer">
                  <span class="weekdays">
                  Mon
                  </span> 
                  <span class="time">
                  9-10pm
                  </span> 
                  <span class="subscriberCounts">
                  2300000
                  </span>
                  <span class="border">
                  </span>
                  <span class="subscriberPercentage">
                  23%
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="dataContainer">
                  <span class="weekdays">
                  T
                  </span> 
                  <span class="time">
                  9-10pm
                  </span> 
                  <span class="subscriberCounts">
                  23
                  </span>
                  <span class="border">
                  </span>
                  <span class="subscriberPercentage">
                  23%
                  </span>
               </div>
```

Comment: thanks,is dispaly:block required because when I remove it i see no effect

Comment: as u suggested to use display:block,so can i replace span with div?

Comment: Yes actually you can get rid of `display: block;` as long as float is used.  I forgot that an element that is floated is automatically `display: block;`.  It should work fine for div's as well but there really isn't any advantage to using divs in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS and it should work the way you wanted. :D

```css
.weekdays{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;  
}

.time{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.subscriberCounts{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.border{
  width: 5%;
  float: left;
}

.subscriberPercentage{
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bootstrapping it? Like with a column layout, that way it becomes easier and responsive as well.

Thanks!